# jQuery find input value from parent siblings

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of html code like the one below:

```
<div>
    <div><input id='route' value='1'></div>
    <div>
        <select id='selID'>
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to get the value from the input once I select any option from select element
I have tried something like this, but still with no succes:

```
$(document).on('change', '#selID', function (event) {
    alert($(this).parent().siblings('div').children('input').val());    
});
```

Could someone give me a solution?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: your code works http://jsbin.com/xutumo/1/

Comment: it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/rn6jq3hn/

Comment: Indeed, it works now after a couple of F5..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this -

```
$("#selID").on('change', function(){

    var $a = $(this);
    if($a.val() != ""){
        alert($a.parent().parent().find('input').val());
    }

    return false;
});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/vzmzu6zc/

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$('#selID')` instead of `$('document')`

```
$('#selID').on('change', function (event) {
    alert($(this).parent().siblings('div').children('input').val());    
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/mo00e3xe/)**

Comment: Now, after seeing the fiddle example, it works using your code, but why wouldn't it work using a jQuery standard .on() statement?

Comment: Since you try to change on the selection menu.